# R : How to import in my dataframe a variable from another dataframe that respond to a logical test based upon matching variables / observations?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem *playing* with three data.frame.

One is coming from the [UNHCR](http://popstats.unhcr.org/en/overview) (I only kept countries from Europe) :

```
'data.frame':   41 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Country        : chr  "Albania" "Austria" "Belarus" "Belgium" ...
 $ 2005           : num  92 62770 13202 34593 199518 ...
 $ 2011           : num  106 72046 8036 42107 177653 ...
 $ 2012           : num  7560 74712 7607 41053 177260 ...
 $ 2013           : num  7767 78956 7404 39578 163730 ...
 $ 2014           : num  8026 79285 7628 41719 144115 ...
```

The second is coming from the [World Bank (population, total)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL) :

```
'data.frame':   2640 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ iso2c      : chr  "1A" "1A" "1A" "1A" ...
 $ country    : chr  "Arab World" "Arab World" "Arab World" "Arab World" ...
 $ SP.POP.TOTL: num  3.37e+08 3.21e+08 3.13e+08 3.29e+08 3.77e+08 ...
 $ year       : num  2008 2006 2005 2007 2013 ...
 $ iso3c      : Factor w/ 248 levels "ABW","AFG","AGO",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ region     : Factor w/ 8 levels "Aggregates","East Asia & Pacific (all income levels)",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ capital    : Factor w/ 211 levels "","Abu Dhabi",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ longitude  : Factor w/ 211 levels "","-0.126236",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ latitude   : Factor w/ 211 levels "","-0.229498",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ income     : Factor w/ 7 levels "Aggregates","High income: nonOECD",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ lending    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Aggregates","Blend",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Finally, the last one is from the **UNDP** (Human Development Index) (I can't post the link as I don't have enough "*reputation*" to post more than 2 links, but you can find it quite easily through a quick google search) :

```
'data.frame':   189 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ HDI.Rank: int  171 85 83 34 149 58 40 85 2 23 ...
 $ Country : chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Andorra" ...
 $ X1980   : Factor w/ 96 levels "","0.190","0.199",..: 4 59 1 1 1 1 71 1 1 85 ...
 $ X1985   : Factor w/ 104 levels "","0.199","0.207",..: 5 62 1 1 1 1 77 1 1 93 ...
 $ X1990   : Factor w/ 127 levels "","0.214","0.218",..: 9 68 53 1 1 1 89 70 127 115 ...
 $ X1995   : Factor w/ 129 levels "","0.232","0.241",..: 10 64 56 1 1 1 96 59 128 115 ...
 $ X2000   : Factor w/ 144 levels "","0.257","0.284",..: 13 74 68 1 19 1 107 69 143 127 ...
 $ X2005   : Factor w/ 153 levels "","0.289","0.324",..: 17 85 79 1 29 1 112 85 152 131 ...
 $ X2010   : Factor w/ 159 levels "0.326","0.362",..: 17 90 92 128 35 115 124 89 158 142 ...
 $ X2011   : Factor w/ 159 levels "0.333","0.368",..: 18 94 95 126 37 115 125 91 158 143 ...
 $ X2012   : Factor w/ 163 levels "0.342","0.373",..: 20 95 97 133 36 114 129 94 162 143 ...
 $ X2013   : Factor w/ 161 levels "0.345","0.348",..: 20 91 92 130 37 111 126 90 160 141 ...
 $ X2014   : Factor w/ 160 levels "0.348","0.350",..: 18 88 90 130 37 110 125 88 159 140 ...
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract some key variables from the second (**SP.POP.TOTL**) and the third data.frames (**X2005, X2011, X2012, X2013, X2014**) to my first data.frame (based upon the UNHCR).

I succeeded to do so with the second data.frame with this command (the `sum` is here as I have needed to regroup two countries in one in order to make some coherence between the variables `base$Country` (**UNHCR**) and `pop$country` (**World Bank**)) :

```
>base$pop2005 = NA
>for(pays in base$Country){base$pop2005[base$Country == pays] = sum(pop$SP.POP.TOTL[pop$year == 2005 & pop$country == pays])}
```

which (in combination of the same command replicated with `pop$year == 2011` and so on) gave me a renewed version of my first data.frame :

```
'data.frame':   41 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Country        : chr  "Albania" "Austria" "Belarus" "Belgium" ...
 $ 2005           : num  92 62770 13202 34593 199518 ...
 $ 2011           : num  106 72046 8036 42107 177653 ...
 $ 2012           : num  7560 74712 7607 41053 177260 ...
 $ 2013           : num  7767 78956 7404 39578 163730 ...
 $ 2014           : num  8026 79285 7628 41719 144115 ...
 $ pop2005        : num  3011487 8227829 9663000 10478617 3833377 ...
 $ pop2011        : num  2904780 8391643 9473000 11047744 3832310 ...
 $ pop2012        : num  2900247 8429991 9464000 11128246 3828419 ...
 $ pop2013        : num  2896652 8479375 9466000 11182817 3823533 ...
 $ pop2014        : num  2893654 8541575 9483000 11231213 3817554 ...
```

But for some, *I think either mystical or due to my lack of knowledge*, reasons this command would not work with the third data.frame...
As I tried this command :

```
>base$idh2005 = NA
>for(pays in base$Country)base$idh2005[base$Country == pays] = hdi$X2005[hdi$Country == pays]
```

Strictly speaking, the command works. But in place of the variable hdi$X2005 I get the variable HDI.Rank (while it is nowhere to be found in the command). I tried to suppress the variable HDI.Rank with `hdi$HDI.Rank <- NULL` but it didn't give any results.

Did I do something wrong in my command ? (By the way, all the names in the first, second and third data frames are corrected to be similar).

In advance, many thanks for taking the time to read me and for anyone able to come with a response ! :)

***Post scriptum*** : As asked by *allinr* here's the `dput` of my data frames.

base (**UNHCR**) :

```
structure(list(Country = c("Albania", "Austria", "Belarus", "Belgium", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", 
"Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Georgia", "Germany", 
"Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", 
"Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Monaco", 
"Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Portugal", "Moldova", 
"Romania", "Serbia and Kosovo (S/RES/1244 (1999))", "Slovak Republic", 
"Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Macedonia, FYR", 
"Ukraine", "United Kingdom"), `2005` = c(92, 62770, 13202, 34593, 
199518, 5218, 10867, 13769, 2726, 45457, 136015, 12658, 179541, 
238602, 783980, 14257, 8922, 375, 9531, 21615, 418658, 210, 9295, 
1896, 2088, 0, 0, 139725, 44177, 363, 1775, 2720, 486938, 3075, 
1151, 5401, 96402, 63448, 4448, 76860, 316590), `2011` = c(106, 
72046, 8036, 42107, 177653, 7072, 23944, 6562, 3358, 18712, 97808, 
15209, 260641, 276088, 659820, 45810, 5555, 245, 13687, 72763, 
312688, 153, 4379, 4728, 8409, 37, 21248, 87956, 54960, 653, 
2268, 2158, 309391, 840, 262, 6935, 117399, 67426, 2921, 46625, 
211461), `2012` = c(7560, 74712, 7607, 41053, 177260, 3558, 23998, 
6267, 4882, 17706, 94305, 13903, 268966, 281870, 682000, 38527, 
4551, 297, 11871, 79654, 281056, 124, 5077, 4326, 9015, 37, 20224, 
85056, 54835, 1233, 2259, 1620, 304567, 2448, 311, 7337, 127871, 
72532, 2541, 42904, 169764), `2013` = c(7767, 78956, 7404, 39578, 
163730, 8880, 19875, 6534, 4798, 19383, 91376, 14906, 285468, 
259574, 335562, 73027, 4439, 477, 11581, 90267, 268143, 116, 
4882, 2116, 10808, 34, 20200, 77137, 54585, 1357, 2366, 2217, 
291139, 2562, 249, 9251, 163999, 74678, 2977, 41720, 151840), 
    `2014` = c(8026, 79285, 7628, 41719, 144115, 17898, 19599, 
    7602, 5120, 26844, 88262, 15874, 309525, 265589, 455439, 
    42882, 18675, 426, 10577, 140626, 263230, 173, 4796, 2473, 
    6275, 33, 20978, 91393, 56472, 1052, 2523, 2878, 271473, 
    2678, 354, 13582, 226149, 83628, 3260, 867451, 154292), pop2005 = c(3011487, 
    8227829, 9663000, 10478617, 3833377, 7739900, 4442000, 1032586, 
    10211216, 5419432, 1354775, 5246096, 63179356, 4190000, 82469422, 
    10987314, 10087065, 296734, 4159914, 57969484, 2238799, 34852, 
    3322528, 465158, 403834, 33808, 614261, 16319868, 4623291, 
    10503330, 3595187, 21319685, 9146549, 5372807, 2000474, 43653155, 
    9029572, 7437115, 2042894, 47105150, 60401206), pop2011 = c(2904780, 
    8391643, 9473000, 11047744, 3832310, 7348328, 4280622, 1116644, 
    10496088, 5570572, 1327439, 5388272, 65342776, 3875000, 81797673, 
    11104899, 9971727, 319014, 4576794, 59379449, 2059709, 36537, 
    3028115, 518347, 416268, 37189, 620079, 16693074, 4953088, 
    10557560, 3559986, 20147528, 9025056, 5398384, 2052843, 46742697, 
    9449213, 7912398, 2065888, 45706100, 63258918), pop2012 = c(2900247, 
    8429991, 9464000, 11128246, 3828419, 7305888, 4267558, 1129303, 
    10510785, 5591572, 1322696, 5413971, 65659790, 3825000, 80425823, 
    11045011, 9920362, 320716, 4586897, 59539717, 2034319, 36791, 
    2987773, 530946, 419455, 37404, 620601, 16754962, 5018573, 
    10514844, 3559519, 20058035, 9004277, 5407579, 2057159, 46773055, 
    9519374, 7996861, 2069270, 45593300, 63700300), pop2013 = c(2896652, 
    8479375, 9466000, 11182817, 3823533, 7265115, 4255689, 1141652, 
    10514272, 5614932, 1317997, 5438972, 65972097, 3776000, 82132753, 
    10965211, 9893082, 323764, 4598294, 60233948, 2012647, 37040, 
    2957689, 543360, 423374, 37528, 621207, 16804432, 5079623, 
    10457295, 3558566, 19983693, 8982249, 5413393, 2059953, 46620045, 
    9600379, 8089346, 2072543, 45489600, 64128226), pop2014 = c(2893654, 
    8541575, 9483000, 11231213, 3817554, 7223938, 4238389, 1153658, 
    10525347, 5643475, 1314545, 5461512, 66495940, 3727000, 80982500, 
    10892413, 9866468, 327386, 4617225, 60789140, 1993782, 37286, 
    2932367, 556319, 427364, 37623, 621810, 16865008, 5137232, 
    10401062, 3556397, 19908979, 8943347, 5418649, 2061980, 46480882, 
    9696110, 8188649, 2075625, 45362900, 64613160), pourcentage2005 = c(0.00305496918963954, 
    0.762898694175584, 0.136624236779468, 0.330129443608827, 
    5.20475810232075, 0.0674168916911071, 0.244642053129221, 
    1.33344825515744, 0.0266961349167425, 0.838777938352211, 
    10.039674484693, 0.24128418542093, 0.284176685814904, 5.6945584725537, 
    0.950631132106152, 0.129758738122893, 0.0884499108511742, 
    0.126375811332709, 0.229115313441576, 0.0372868594103753, 
    18.7001155530264, 0.602547916905773, 0.279756859836847, 0.407603437971614, 
    0.51704413199483, 0, 0, 0.856165013099371, 0.955531460165497, 
    0.00345604679658737, 0.0493715625918763, 0.0127581622336353, 
    5.3237346675779, 0.0572326532481066, 0.05753636388176, 0.0123725306910806, 
    1.06762535367125, 0.853126514784295, 0.217730337452653, 0.16316687241204, 
    0.524145163591601), pourcentage2011 = c(0.0036491575954117, 
    0.858544625885539, 0.0848305710968014, 0.381136637489066, 
    4.63566360758916, 0.0962395799425393, 0.559357962464333, 
    0.587653719538188, 0.0319928720109816, 0.335908053966451, 
    7.3681728501272, 0.282261177609445, 0.398882655368055, 7.12485161290323, 
    0.806648863959736, 0.412520636162472, 0.0557075018198954, 
    0.0767991373419348, 0.299052131251701, 0.122539028612408, 
    15.1811736512294, 0.418753592248953, 0.144611416673409, 0.912130291098434, 
    2.02009282481478, 0.0994917852053026, 3.42666015136781, 0.526901156731229, 
    1.10961081248708, 0.00618514126370108, 0.063708115706073, 
    0.0107109914427219, 3.42813385313066, 0.0155602120931005, 
    0.0127627879969389, 0.014836542273117, 1.24242092965837, 
    0.852156324795593, 0.14139198252761, 0.102010453746874, 0.33427855974394
    ), pourcentage2012 = c(0.260667453496202, 0.886264291385364, 
    0.0803782755705833, 0.368908092074888, 4.63010971369644, 
    0.0487004454489311, 0.562335649568207, 0.554944067269811, 
    0.0464475298467241, 0.316655137410374, 7.1297561949231, 0.256798568001195, 
    0.409635790793726, 7.36915032679739, 0.847986348862106, 0.348818122498927, 
    0.0458753420490099, 0.0926052956509809, 0.258802410431278, 
    0.13378296709069, 13.8157289982545, 0.337038949743144, 0.169925894637913, 
    0.814772123718796, 2.14921743691218, 0.0989199016148005, 
    3.25877657303163, 0.50764663029376, 1.09264127472092, 0.0117262795339617, 
    0.0634636309006919, 0.00807656383090367, 3.38247035270017, 
    0.0452697963358464, 0.015117936921745, 0.0156863818281701, 
    1.34327110165017, 0.90700588643469, 0.122796928385373, 0.0941015456218348, 
    0.266504239383488), pourcentage2013 = c(0.268137145918806, 
    0.931153534311196, 0.0782167758292838, 0.353917979700464, 
    4.28216521212188, 0.122227934451141, 0.467021908790797, 0.572328520424788, 
    0.0456332116954935, 0.345204536760196, 6.93294446041986, 
    0.274059142058462, 0.432710210803213, 6.87431144067797, 0.408560516655274, 
    0.665988096353093, 0.0448697382676096, 0.147329536328931, 
    0.251854274650555, 0.149860673253561, 13.3229026252492, 0.31317494600432, 
    0.165061302929416, 0.389428739693757, 2.55282563407295, 0.0905990193988489, 
    3.25173412405205, 0.459027713641258, 1.07458762195541, 0.0129765871575776, 
    0.0664874559021808, 0.0110940455300229, 3.24127064391112, 
    0.0473270645600643, 0.012087654427067, 0.019843395689558, 
    1.70825547616401, 0.923164864007548, 0.143639963079174, 0.0917132707256164, 
    0.236775612660796), pourcentage2014 = c(0.277365573078191, 
    0.928224595581026, 0.0804386797426975, 0.37145587034989, 
    3.77506120411132, 0.247759601480522, 0.462416262405362, 0.658947452364566, 
    0.0486444769944402, 0.475664373457843, 6.71426234933, 0.290652112455305, 
    0.465479546570813, 7.12607995707003, 0.562391874787763, 0.393686871770286, 
    0.189277459775879, 0.130121630124685, 0.229076988884016, 
    0.231334083686659, 13.2025467177455, 0.463981118918629, 0.16355387985201, 
    0.444529128072203, 1.46830336668507, 0.0877123036440475, 
    3.37369936154131, 0.541909022515732, 1.09926902269549, 0.010114351784462, 
    0.0709425859936334, 0.0144557890186132, 3.03547430285328, 
    0.0494219131004795, 0.0171679647717243, 0.0292206159082782, 
    2.33236834153078, 1.02126736657048, 0.157061126166817, 1.91224767375983, 
    0.238793459412912)), .Names = c("Country", "2005", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "pop2005", "pop2011", "pop2012", "pop2013", 
"pop2014", "pourcentage2005", "pourcentage2011", "pourcentage2012", 
"pourcentage2013", "pourcentage2014"), row.names = c(NA, 41L), class = "data.frame")
```

and for hdi (**UNDP**) : the body is limited to 30000 characters; with the dput of this data frame I have 47259, I'll post it in another post here.

Scott

Comment: @allinr I don't have the space to post both of the dput, please let me know when you've finished to read the first data.frame's dput and I'll post the third (or the second if you need it), thank you so much for your help :) 
Scott

Comment: Am I missing something, don't you have to just merge all three dataframes by country column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making following two assumptions (let me know if it is not true):

1. First column of each `data.frame` is the country name
2. The country name appears only once in each `data.frame`

   ```
   #Generate example data from R's mtcars data
   car_names = rownames(mtcars)
   list1 = cbind(car_names,data.frame(mtcars[,c(1,2,3,4)]))
   list2 = cbind(car_names,data.frame(mtcars[,c(5,6,7,8)]))
   list3 = cbind(car_names,data.frame(mtcars[,c(9,10,11)]))    
   #Remove rownames
   rownames(list1) = NULL
   rownames(list2) = NULL
   rownames(list3) = NULL
   # Now the example data is ready

   # We will use lookup command from qdapTools package
   library(qdapTools)

   #Add specific values from list2 or list3 to list1 based on car_names
   list1$gear = lookup(list1$car_names,list3) # Add gear from list3 to list1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Consider reshaping the `pop` dataframe since you need long to wide transformation of your select years, then merge all dataframes. Below renames columns and runs a chain merge using `Reduce` on list of data frames:

```
# RESHAPE DATAFRAME LONG TO WIDE
popwide <- reshape(pop[c("country", "year", "SP.POP.TOTL"), idvar = "country", 
                   timevar = "year", direction = "wide")
# PREFIX YEAR COLS WITH pop
names(popwide) <- gsub("ST.POP.", "pop", names(popwide))

# RENAMING TO LOWER CASE country FOR CHAIN MERGE
names(base)[2] <- "country"
names(hdi)[2] <- "country"
# PREFIX YEAR COLS WITH idh
names(hdi) <- gsub("X", "idh", names(hdi))

# CHAIN MERGE
finaldf <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="country", all=T), list(base, popwide, hdi))
```